# Hyphen in ng-class's object key causing syntax error during compile... but not breaking anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i've run into an error with the following code developing locally

```
<div data-ng-if="statuses.notifications.length < 6" data-ng-bind="message" 
data-ng-class="{col-md-10:statuses.notifications.length == 1}" class="siteMessage">
```

The problematic bit coming from the hyphens in the key in the object assignment for ng-class.

```
{col-md-10:statuses.notifications.length == 1}
```

But nothing is actually breaking, does anyone have experience with this or know more about this error and why nothing is breaking?

Error log:

```
angular.js:13642 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$parse/syntax?p0=-&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%…%20%3D%3D%201%7D&p4=-md-10%3Astatuses.notifications.length%20%3D%3D%201%7D
at Error (native)
at http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
at Object.throwError (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:228:143)
at Object.consume (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:228:318)
at Object.object (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:228:53)
at Object.primary (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:224:68)
at Object.unary (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:223:411)
at Object.multiplicative (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:223:157)
at Object.additive (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:222:493)
at Object.relational (http://127.0.0.1:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:222:328) <div data-ng-if="statuses.notifications.length < 6" data-ng-bind="message" data-ng-class="{col-md-10:statuses.notifications.length == 1}" class="siteMessage ng-binding ng-scope">
```

The error link (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=-&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=5&p3=%7Bcol-md-10:statuses.notifications.length%20%3D%3D%201%7D&p4=-md-10:statuses.notifications.length%20%3D%3D%201%7D) tells me that it is a syntax error during the compile, but it doesn't say anything like... it's cool though, nothing is gonna break, we're just logging it for fun haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall right, you should quote the part with `col-md-10` and add a space after the colon as follows: `data-ng-class="{'col-md-10': statuses.notifications.length == 1}"`

Edited by suggestion from @andrew-clavin (couldn't find how to accept the suggestion, I hope textual credit is ok :) )

Comment: the quotes seem to be breaking it, i was thinking about setting up an object that looked identical in scope and wrapping it in the {{}}, but i was more curious about something pertaining to why the compile error is coming up but breaking nothing on the page

Comment: I usually follow the example from this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass#ngclass-using-evaluated-expression

Edit: pressed enter too fast :p

You could try:
data-ng-class="{'col-md-10': (statuses.notifications.length == 1)}"

or even better, avoid the coercion in the same go:
data-ng-class="{'col-md-10': (statuses.notifications.length === 1)}"

Another option would be to try to remove the "data-"-prefix of the attribute although I highly doubt that will do any difference, I just don't use it, so it's worth a try if everything else fails

Comment: The data prefix is to make it kosher html markup, not that the browser would reject it without it, but this way it follows the spec. Good catch on the coercion. Turns out the ' ' single quotes did fix it once i put in the space after the colon (oops). Thanks @rohde! Still curious about the compile error not breaking anything and it all working still, you think that's pretty common for angular? I don't recall ever running into it.